# openni_launch for kinect xbox 360 -1414

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so,... i don't know what going on..
i'm using Kinect xbox 360, model 1414.
i've succeed run the example of nite (nite/NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/Samples/Bin), but, i tried connected it with ros `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, it shown up:

```
process[camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [15373]
process[camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [15374]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /home/adelleodel/ros/src/openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: The device is not connected!
Image: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.2.1: Failed to set USB interface!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: The device is not connected!

[FATAL] [1454896895.994153086]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1454896895.994256906]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1454896895.994619240]: Service call failed!
```

there's some driver for primesense... and i just download it all. am i wrong to install all of it?
seems that my driver doesn't fit. and i wonder so why i can run my example then? '-'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226018/openni_launch-for-kinect-xbox-360--1414/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears your device is not connected. Have you given permissions for the USB port being used for the kinect?

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2016-02-14**:
how to do it?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2016-02-14**:
Try chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0, this should give Ubuntu read and write permissions on all accounts to access USB ports. It expires after some time / terminal closing or something, so if it works now and doesn't later, just try it again